# btrfs ontop of mdadm raid - calculating stripes for corrupt sectors for use with raid6check

Tags: linux, raid, software-raid, mdadm, btrfs

I've got a setup with btrfs running on top of mdadm raid6 as btrfs's RAID5/6 code isn't stable yet. I figured this way I'd get the benefits of snapshotting and checksumming with a few extra hoops to jump through, now that I actually have to jump through those hoops I'm running into some problems.

This morning my dmesg produced this issue:

```
BTRFS error (device md2): bad tree block start, want 28789209759744 have 7611175298055105740
BTRFS info (device md2): read error corrected: ino 0 off 28789209759744 (dev /dev/md2 sector 55198191488)
BTRFS info (device md2): read error corrected: ino 0 off 28789209763840 (dev /dev/md2 sector 55198191496)
BTRFS info (device md2): read error corrected: ino 0 off 28789209767936 (dev /dev/md2 sector 55198191504)
BTRFS info (device md2): read error corrected: ino 0 off 28789209772032 (dev /dev/md2 sector 55198191512)
```

This is the kind of thing that could have slipped by silently had I not used btrfs so at least it did me some good... so now, I should be be able to figure out which disk has the issue and replace it, right?

Well, mdadm seems to only support determining the failing disk using the raid6check tool, I had to build it from source to get it working on Debian, but after I did so, it seems like I'm in business.

The only catch here is that this tool seems to be extremely slow, to scan 1000 stripes it takes a good 3 minutes. This means to scan the 15261512 stripes that comprise my array it'll take over 31 days. I'd like to avoid that if possible. The mdadm check/repair is much faster, only around 3 days, but doesn't produce any useful information about which disk could be responsible for this, so I don't exactly want to use it.

The raid6check tool appears to support accepting a stripe number - I'm wondering if it's possible to calculate what stripe number to pass it so I can get it to directly check the relevant portion of the disk.

Here's the raid6check information for reference purposes if it helps:

```
layout: 2
disks: 8
component size: 8001427603456
total stripes: 15261512
chunk size: 524288
```

Thanks, any ideas are appreciated.

Comment: I wonder why raid recoverable corruption leaked up to the FS layer

Answer (score 3):

Alright, I got a somewhat working way to do this after talking to JyZyXEL on #linux-raid on Freenode.

raid6check reports total stripes so run it like this to see the basic information without running a full test:

```
./raid6check /dev/md0 0 1
```

You'll get something like this:

```
layout: 2
disks: 8
component size: 8001427603456
total stripes: 15261512
chunk size: 524288
```

Check the total sectors in your RAID using fdisk -l /dev/md0:

```
Disk /dev/md2: 43.7 TiB, 48008565620736 bytes, 93766729728 sectors
```

Now compute sectors per stripe:

```
total sectors / total stripes = 93766729728 / 15261512 = 6144
```

Now just divide the sector with the error by the sectors per stripe:

```
error sector = 55198191488/6144 = 8984080
```

Now run a raid6check, try to include the area around it as this doesn't seem to be exact:

```
raid6check /dev/md0 8984000 1000
```

For me this quickly produced many relevant errors, all pointing to the same disk which could be failing:

```
 Error detected at stripe 8984078, page 100: possible failed disk slot 1: 4 --> /dev/sdj1
 Error detected at stripe 8984081, page 76: possible failed disk slot 4: 4 --> /dev/sdj1
```

From this point, you can act accordingly, replace the disk, run SMART tests, use raid6check's autorepair, etc.

This may not be the most precise method, but I'm posting it just in case no one else comes up with a better idea and someone is looking for a way that does the job in the future.